# Language switcher not visible when logged out (Drupal 7)

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm creating a multilingual website in Drupal 7. I'm using the internationalization and entity translation modules and language detection is set to URL. I use the language switcher (content) from the entity translation module to switch between languages.

Everything works fine as long as I'm logged in as administrator. When I log out, or when I'm just an authenticated user, I can't see the language switcher anymore although the html code is generated.
Does anyone what could be the reason for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to check the permissions on internationalization module; probably you have selected "administrator only".

By the way, read this: [Drupal multilingual](http://drupal.org/documentation/multilingual).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. I tried setting every permission that has something to do with translation to enabled for both anonymous and authenticated user, but the language switcher is still invisible when I'm logged out.